# Not getting mocked object data for repository call inside service method from controller test case?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, spring-data-jpa

Repository object not mocked from controller testcase return empty object here is the below code

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Main.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles(ApplicationConstants.DEVELOPMENT_PROFILE)
public class EmployeeControllerRealTest {
@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext   webAppContext;
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Mock
EmployeeCompositeService  employeeCompositeService;


String name = "mike";

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webAppContext).build();
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void testGetEmployees() throws Exception {

    Mockito.when(employeeRepository.findByName(name)).thenReturn(getEmployees());
    String url = URIConstants.ROOT_CONTEXT + URIConstants.EMPLOYEE;
    MvcResult result =
    mockMvc.perform(post(url)
                    .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                    .content(convertObjectToJsonBytes(name))
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andExpect(content().contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
                    .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].employeeName").value("Mike"))
                    .andReturn();
    String jsonContent = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
    LOGGER.debug("jsonContent: {}",jsonContent);

}

protected byte[] convertObjectToJsonBytes(Object object) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
    return mapper.writeValueAsBytes(object);
}

private List<Employee> getEmployees(){
//here is the logic to get List of employees to return. When the mockito call is invoked.
}

}
```

I have a service call in side EmployeeController i.e employeeCompositeService.getEmployees(String name) 
So I have mocked in the EmployeeControllerTestcase i.e @Mock EmployeeCompositeService  employeeCompositeService;
when I run the controller testcase it invokes further services calls and repository and hit the database 
So I does want to call those services returns the results form my employeeCompositeService.getEmployees(String name) from controller.
Can you please tell me what I did wrong in the above code Thanks in Advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [mocked repository object returns empty results from controller testcase?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32820404/mocked-repository-object-returns-empty-results-from-controller-testcase)

Comment: I have changed the logic to  mock only the service inside of EmployeeController and return results.
I doesn't want to mock employeeService and employeeRepository
I have tried with the updated code in the above post but no luck. Can you please tell me what I did wrong